# Append to compressed tar file with performance

Tags: python, performance, compression

As you might know, Python's `tarfile` does not have the ability to append to the files that compressed with e.g. `gz` or `bz2`. I tried to implement this functionality which works fine but operates slowly. The following function accepts a string or bytes object and appends it as a file to an existing tarfile. I'm not sure if this code has the best performance, and it may have issues. I also tried writing files to memory instead of to a temporary directory, but this didn't impact performance.

```
import os
import tarfile
import tempfile
import time
from pathlib import Path


def append_tar_file(buffer, file_name, output_path, replace=True):
    """
    append a buffer to an existing tar file
    """
    # extract files
    # check for existing file and overwrite if need to
    # compress files
    if not os.path.isfile(output_path):
        return
    buffer = buffer.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(buffer, str) else buffer

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        tempdirp = Path(tempdir)
        with tarfile.open(output_path, "r:bz2") as tar:
            try:
                tar.extractall(os.path.abspath(tempdirp))
            except Exception as err:   #tar file is empty
                print(err)
        buffer_path = os.path.join(tempdir, os.path.basename(file_name))
        if replace or (buffer_path not in list(os.path.abspath(f) for f in tempdirp.iterdir())):
            with open(buffer_path, "wb") as f:
                f.write(buffer)

        with tarfile.open(output_path, "w:bz2") as tar:
            for file in tempdirp.iterdir():
                try:
                    tar.add(file, arcname=os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(file)))
                except Exception as err:
                    print(err)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "./test.tar.gz"
    buffer = "Test String"
    filename = "somefile"
    for i in range(1, 100):
        print(time.time())
        append_tar_file(buffer, filename+str(i), path)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, the `tarfile` package doesn't support appending to a compressed tar.
But I think you can do better than your current attempt.
Instead of extracting the content to disk, you could keep it in memory, write and append to a new compressed file, and finally rename the compressed file.
That way you will write a single temporary file,
instead of many.
The reduced disk I/O should improve the performance.

```
def append_tar_file(buf, file_name, output_path, replace=True):
    """
    append a buf to an existing tar file if not already there, or if replace=True
    """
    if not os.path.isfile(output_path):
        return

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        tmp_path = os.path.join(tempdir, 'tmp.tar.bz2')

        with tarfile.open(output_path, "r:bz2") as tar:
            if not replace:
                if file_name in (member.name for member in tar):
                    return

            if isinstance(buf, str):
                buf = buf.encode("utf-8")

            fileobj = BytesIO(buf)
            tarinfo = tarfile.TarInfo(file_name)
            tarinfo.size = len(fileobj.getvalue())

            with tarfile.open(tmp_path, "w:bz2") as tmp:
                for member in tar:
                    if member.name != file_name:
                        tmp.addfile(member, tar.extractfile(member.name))
                tmp.addfile(tarinfo, fileobj)

        os.rename(tmp_path, output_path)
```

Comment: Can multiprocessing used while working with memory? I mean when adding files back to output tar file use it. When the compressed file getting larger, it would take more time to append.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of hardcoding the compression scheme (and possibly compressing a `.tar.gz` file using BZIP2 as you do), you should try to infer that information. Note that `tarfile` let you open a compressed file without knowing the compression scheme using `tarfile.open(filename, 'r:*')` but there is no equivalent for writing the archive.

Since the compression scheme understood by the `tarfile` module are usual extensions of the files, inspecting the [suffixes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffixes) of `output_path` should be enough:

```
def get_compression(filename):
    suffixes = Path(filename).suffixes
    tar, *compression = (s.lstrip('.') for s in suffixes)

    if tar == 'tgz':
        if compression:
            raise RuntimeError('Too much suffixes, cannot infer compression scheme from {}'.format(''.join(suffixes)))
        return 'gz'

    if tar != 'tar':
        raise RuntimeError('Not a tar archive')

    if not compression:
        return ''

    try:
        compression, = compression
    except ValueError:
        raise RuntimeError('Too much compression scheme: {}'.format(', '.join(compression))) from None
    else:
        return compression
```

Now you can use `compression = get_compression(output_path)` and then open the tar file using `tarfile.open(<name>, 'r:{}'.format(compression))` and open the file for writing using `tarfile.open(<name>, 'w:{}'.format(compression))`.

Note that I used `RuntimeError` here but you should probably come up with something less generic.

Comment: Thanks. The function return `gz` for the files that created with `bz2` in `tarfile`. Thus it should return `bz2` instead of `gz`.

Comment: If your file is named `something.tar.gz`, it is not coherent to use anything else than GZIP compression to create the file. This is the assumption this function is doing, hence the choice to only check the filename and not trying to do anything fancy with the file content. If you store BZIP2 compressed data in a `.tar.gz` this is your mistake to start with.

Comment: So you mean I should use `tar.bz2` right?

Comment: If you want to store BZIP2 compressed data, definitely.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want something fancier based on the file content rather than its name, you can check [how `tarfile` handle the `r:*` mode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/tarfile.py#L1513-L1525). Basically, it tries to open the file using, in turn `gzip.GzipFile`, `bz2.BZ2File`, `lzma.LZMAFile` and if all failed fallback to trying without compression.